# jQuery range slider how to break thousands?

Tags: jquery, rangeslider

I use jQuery slider and i need to break thousands. How i can do it? This is my code.

```
$( function() {
    $( ".ui-slider-handle" ).draggable();
    $( "#penthousePrice" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 10000000,
        max: 1500000000,
        values: [ 100000000, 300000000 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#penthouseAmount" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
            $( "#penthouseAmount2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
        }
        });
        $( "#penthouseAmount" ).val($( "#penthousePrice" ).slider( "values", 0 ));
        $( "#penthouseAmount2" ).val($( "#penthousePrice" ).slider( "values", 1 ));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Just use .toLocaleString('ru-RU'));
now my code

```
$( function() {
    $( ".ui-slider-handle" ).draggable();
    $( "#penthousePrice" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 10000000,
        max: 1500000000,
        values: [ 100000000, 300000000 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#penthouseAmount" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ].toLocaleString('ru-RU'));
            $( "#penthouseAmount2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ].toLocaleString('ru-RU'));
        }
        });
        $( "#penthouseAmount" ).val($( "#penthousePrice" ).slider( "values", 0 ).toLocaleString('ru-RU')) ;
        $( "#penthouseAmount2" ).val($( "#penthousePrice" ).slider( "values", 1 ).toLocaleString('ru-RU')) ;
});
```